# Como evitar que se ponga un campo nulo al realizar una elección múltiple en VBA Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

Tengo en access una tabla con los campos Nombre, apellidos y Validado. También hay varios formularios.En uno de ellos tengo un listbox, con el que accedo a los datos mediante una secuencia sql. Mi intención es poder elegir varios nombres y apellidos, y que al darle a un checkbox el campo validado cambie a que sí lo están. El problema que al usar la propiedad SelectedItems, los nombres me los pone a nulos. Y me gustaría saber como se podría hacer para que mantuviera los nombres sin que los cambiasen.
¿Cómo se puede resolver? ¿Se os ocurre alguna otra manera?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Creo que unos datos de ejemplo ayudarían a la pregunta.

Comment: Claro: Por ejemplo tenemos una lista donde aparecen los nombres: Luis Pérez, Carlos Núñez y Mario Velazquez, pertenecientes a una BBDD. Otro campo llamado Saludado que siempre pone no y un chekbox. Al marcar una persona y darle al chek, el campo Saludado se cambia a sí, pero el problema es que cuando uso Item Selected, el nombre de la persona, por ejemplo si se ha señalado a Carlos Nuñez se pone a Null. Hay alguna manera de seleccionar y que no cambie el nombre? O de qué manera se puede almacenar los nombres en un array?

Comment: No me refería a que lo contases, sino a que edites la pregunta y añadas unos datos de ejemplo, para poder simular tu situación y dar una respuesta. Enseña lo que tienes, y lo que te gustaría conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

> También hay varios formularios.En uno de ellos tengo un listbox, con el que accedo a los datos mediante una secuencia sql

Quiero pensar que el o los formularios que tienes, están en visualización de Hoja de datos o Formularios Continuos.

> Mi intención es poder elegir varios nombres y apellidos, y que al darle a un checkbox el campo validado cambie a que sí lo están.

La propiedad que estas intentando utilizar "SelectedItems", yo la he utilizado al trabajar con Nodos, yo para tu problema, tomando en cuenta que tienes el cuadro combinado en un formulario, jugaría con el source del cuadro combinado, en el evento Current del formulario; dicho evento se encarga de cuando se activa el registro, no afecta al mismo control, si este lo utilizas mas de una vez, por ejemplo:

[image: En esta imagen como puedes ver, estoy afectando el mismo control y no se ha puesto en NULL el registro anterior, a pesar de tener el mismo source.]

Esto sucede en el evento Current o "Al activar el registro" del formulario, seteas la consulta SQL segun tus necesidades en el evento del formulario, y de esta forma no se modificara el valor del campo.